# MYSQL 1:M Recursive Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to figure out this question all day, I've created a table and trying to make a Select statement that would answer this question

> Who are the mothers in the Simpsons family tree? List them from oldest
>   to youngest.

With my current data I don't know how I would go about doing this with only one table.

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
persID           INT IDENTITY(1,1),
persFName        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
persLName        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
persGender       CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
persDOB          DATE NOT NULL,
persDOD          DATE ,
fatherID         INT ,
motherID         INT ,

CONSTRAINT pk_person_persID PRIMARY KEY(persID),
CONSTRAINT fk_person_fatherID FOREIGN KEY (fatherID) REFERENCES person(persID),
CONSTRAINT fk_person_motherID FOREIGN KEY (motherID) REFERENCES person(persID),


);
```

And this is my data

```
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ('Abraham', 'Simpson', 'M', '1944-01-15', '2015-07-21',NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ('Mona', 'Simpson', 'F', '1946-09-22', NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Herb', 'Simpson', 'M', '1963-11-21',NULL,1,2)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Homer', 'Simpson', 'M', '1965-05-19',NULL,1,2)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Clancy', 'Bouvier', 'F', '1945-02-12',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Jackie', 'Bouvier', 'M', '1945-12-01','2016-05-15',NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Marge', 'Simpson', 'F', '1966-05-18',NULL,6,5)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Patty', 'Bouvier', 'F', '1964-01-08',NULL,6,5)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Selma', 'Bouvier', 'F', '1969-03-01',NULL,6,5)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Bart', 'Simpson', 'M', '1990-01-01',NULL,4,7)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Lisa', 'Simpson', 'F', '1992-05-15',NULL,4,7)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Maggie', 'Simpson', 'F', '1997-11-28',NULL,4,7)
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID) VALUES ( 'Ling', 'Bouvier', 'M', '2000-04-02',NULL,NULL,9)
```

Comment: You would want to do something along these lines-- select entries based on the mother attribute, and then sort the results based on date of birth.
Also, make sure that you have the correct database select, otherwise the select statement with throw an error.

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS SQL Server? Your title says one but your tags the other.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are looking for but I am not sure if it is the smartest way! I hope this help.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT T2.motherID, 
                    T1.persID, 
                    T1.PersFName, 
                    T1.PersLName,
                    T1.PersGender,
                    T1.PersDOB,
                    T1.PersDOD,
                    T1.FatherID,
                    T1.MotherID
    FROM person AS T1
    LEFT JOIN person  AS T2 ON T1.persID = T2.motherID
    WHERE T2.motherID IS NOT NULL
    AND T1.persLName = 'Simpson'
    ORDER BY T1.persDOB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE persID IN (SELECT DISTINCT motherID FROM person)
    AND persLNAme = 'Simpson'
ORDER BY persDOB ASC;
```

The idea is to get all mothers' IDs and then to extract them from the base table. Then we are using `ORDER BY` clause to sort the result.

[image]